# Longrunning tasks: reporting progress or controlling execution after invocation

Tags: c#, callback

I wrote a function that uses DLL for its purposes. the class where this function  is present has callback for dll for monitoring this function state and a field that I must use in another class.
While I am calling this function in target class I must contineusly get this field value (for progress bar) or pass "Halt" in this callback but it only possible when function finishes execute/ 
 How could I do this?
There is My code. I need to cancel engine via progressbar dialog Cancel

```
 class LibWrap //containing the LONG process with dll
{
public bool cancelThisBoringProcess;
public int currentPecentage;
public delegate void  pfnCallback(int progress, out bool cancel);
public void showProgress(int progress, out bool cancel)
{
 cancel = cancelThisBoringProcess; 
 currentPecentage = progress;
} 
[DllImport("Lib.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public unsafe static extern byte* bufferOp(byte* data,pfnCallback del);
public unsafe  BitmapFrame engine(BitmapFrame incomingFrame)
{
//...
 fixed (byte* inBuf = incoming)
 {
var callback = new pfnCallback(showProgress);
byte* outBuf = bufferOp(inBuf, callback);//this is DLL function with callback to get out percentage //and pass cancel
      GC.KeepAlive(callback);
//....
}
}
}
class Main
{
void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog("");
LibWrap lwrap = new LibWrap();
DoWorkEventHandler handler = delegate { BitmapFrame bf = lwrap.engine(img)); };

            dlg.AutoIncrementInterval = 100;
            dlg.IsCancellingEnabled = true;
            dlg.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            dlg.RunWorkerThread(handler);
}
}
```

//the ProgressDialog is from http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/01/wpf-progress-dialog

Comment: I updated my my question with code

Comment: And I just updated my answer to match your updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mentioned it, but here is the callback pattern:

```
void LongOperation(object someParam, Function<int, bool> callback)
{
      int progress = 0;
      while (progress++<100)
      {
          // lengthy operation:
          Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1);

          if (!callback(progress)) 
              break;
      } 
}
```

This also shows how a callback can be used to interrupt/cancel the long operation

```
bool alwaysCancelAt30Seconds(int progress)
{
     if ((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalSeconds <= 30)
     {
          form1.lblProgress.Text = progress.ToString();
     } else
     {
          form1.lblProgress.Text = "canceled due to timeout!";
          return false;     // means 'abort'
     }
     return true;           // means 'continue'
}

  // call site:
  LongOperation(new [] { "some", "data" }, alwaysCancelAt30Seconds);
```

Comment: Sorry for once more question. But how to stop process not after 30 sec but by pressing cancel (for example). If I write alwaysCancelAt30Seconds(bool stop) then I need two different incoming params - one is false and another is true (true = stop when user select such cancel)  LongOperation(new [] { "some", "data" }, alwaysCancelAt30Seconds); - there is no CURRENT state of parameters of alwaysCancelAt30Seconds function

Comment: Since alwaysCancelAt30Seconds is any delegate you can just refer to external variables (e.g. members of the surrounding class) for state

Comment: I ll do so but the process in dll is still running.(( My progress window shoot an BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync(); right now as I press canlel but a loop in void Processing( bool stop) 
still continues till end perhaps there is something with my code.(( I am trying to call like DoWorkEventHandler handler = delegate { BitmapFrame bf = lwrap.engine(data, CancelByDemand); };

Comment: Where         int CancelByDemand(LibWrap libPtr)
        {
            libPtr.SetCancelForProcess = stop;
            return libPtr.GetCurrentPercentage;
        }

Comment: And function engine in LibWrap described as:  public unsafe  BitmapFrame engine(Data dat, Func<LibWrap,int> progressCallBack)

Comment: I thought that I could do this - recive current percentage and set false if process too long/   I am very sorry for my questions but I am really stuck(

Comment: @PapaJohn: please just edit the question with your real code. This is all way too cryptic. And yes, you must be doing something wrong, and probably quite simple, but there is no way I can get myself to psychic-debug this out of your comments.